# how to apply ONLY my changes to a file in git

Tags: git, gerrit

This will be a basic question in git, please excuse me, as i am starting on git..

I  had a repo repoA and i changed some file, say file A , there some times back. Now repoA is throwing some messages to me while pushing the code. So  I created another repo repoB and I want to commit the file A to repo B. But the file A in repo B is modified by some one else recently  and he added some more codes. Now I want to add my changes to this file in repoB and push it. 
Note: I want to apply my changes over his  change such that his change remains there.

Answer (score 2):

When you `push` the code, you will first be asked to `pull`.

Unless your code changes are on the same line as his, there would be an auto-merge and both code blocks will be there.

If there is a conflict in the code, you will have to manually remove the conflict and fix the code before you code push.

Answer (score 0):

1) Clone the repo B

```
git clone GERRIT-SERVER/repo-b
cd repo-b
```

2) Add the repo A as a remote and fetch its changes

```
git remote add repo-b GERRIT-SERVER/repo-a
git fetch repo-b
```

3) Cherry-pick the commit which you've created the file A

```
git cherry-pick COMMIT
```

If needed resolve the conflicts and then push to repo-b